# Replace specific character and divide remainder

Tags: r

I have the following example data frame:

```
Date <- c("2013-01-01","2013-01-10","2013-01-16","2013-01-19")
concentration1 <- c("12","<10","<2","14")
concentration2 <- c("10","<10","<5","15")
y <- data.frame(Date, concentration1,concentration2)
y$Date <- as.Date(y$Date)
```

I need to search the data frame for the "<" symbol, delete it and divide the remainder by 2. I was trying to get the result with the following code:

```
y <- data.frame(lapply(y, function(x) {
  gsub("<", "", x)
 }))
```

However, I was not able to divide the remainder by 2.

UPDATE:

This is my original code with my data based on reply from @RHertel:

```
hw13<-read.csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/dw6fket1b0bmoll/HW2013_%20Doemitz.csv?dl=1",sep=";",header=TRUE)

hw13$Datum<-as.Date(hw13$Datum, format="%d.%m.%Y")#convert to date
hw13[] <- lapply(hw13, as.character)     
hw13[sapply(hw13, startsWith, "<")] <- as.numeric(substring(hw13[sapply(hw13, startsWith, "<")],2)) / 2
```

Comment: The `concentration` columns will be of type `character` you now need to make it `numeric` e.g. `y$concentration1 <-as.numeric(y$concentration1)` etc.. Then you can do arithmetic.

Comment: If you add `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to the `read.csv()` command you won't need the `hw13[] <- lapply(hw13, as.character)` part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can identify the entries that need to be modified with `sapply` combined with `startsWith`, and perform the required operations (remove the `<`, convert into numeric, divide by 2) on these elements.

```
y[] <- lapply(y, as.character)     
y[sapply(y, startsWith, "<")] <- as.numeric(substring(y[sapply(y, startsWith, "<")],2)) / 2

#> y
#        Date concentration1 concentration2
#1 2013-01-01             12             10
#2 2013-01-10              5              5
#3 2013-01-16              1            2.5
#4 2013-01-19             14             15
```

The columns 2 and 3 containing the concentrations can be converted to numeric like this:

```
y[2:3] <- sapply(y[2:3], as.numeric)
```

Comment: When I run ´y[2:3] <- sapply(y[2:3], as.numeric)` the concentration values change.

Comment: I can't confirm this. Did you run the entire code as I posted it, including the first line with `lapply`?

Comment: This will convert all your columns to characters, including the date, then `as.numeric` is used on individual elements, so it's coerced back to character in the end. Try `str(y)` on the output, all columns are characters. Columns that would start as numeric would have become characters as well.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper I agree, but you may have overlooked that at the end I posted how to convert the concentrations to numeric. The date type in column 1 could be restored  with `y$Date <- as.Date(y$Date)`. For the example posted by the OP this is not a problem. If the real data contains several columns of different type that need to be preserved it may be better to make a copy of the columns that need to be changed.

Comment: this is mostly because of the first line, we could avoid this by using `sapply(y, grepl, pattern= "^<")` instead of `startsWith` as `grepl` supports factors as input.

Comment: @RHertel I ran your code with my data and it introduces NAs to the values where there is a ´<´ sign instead of removing the `<´ sign and dividing the remaining value by 2.

Comment: @RHertel Ok, I can see that. But I am converting everything in my data to character as well but it doesn´t work for my data frame. Any ideas?

Comment: probably you try to convert to numeric too early then you get these NAs, I don't think it comes from @RHertel's code

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper The only part where I convert to numeric is in `y[sapply(y, startsWith, "<")] <- as.numeric(substring(y[sapply(y, startsWith, "<")],2)) / 2`. I am not converting the frame to numeric before.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper @RHertel I figured out what the problem was: Unfortunaltely, Germans use `,` as decimal separator and when the code removed the `<`, the remaining value had a `,` as a separator which was then not recognised as a number by R hence the `NA`. I did a `gsub`to replace the `,` whith a `.` and now it´s all working.

Answer (score 2):

```
y[2:3] <- lapply(y[2:3],function(x){
  x <- as.character(x) # if it's a factor
  flag    <- startsWith(x,"<")
  x       <- as.numeric(gsub("^<","",x))
  x[flag] <- x[flag] / 2
  x
})

#          Date concentration1 concentration2
# 1 2013-01-01             12           10.0
# 2 2013-01-10              5            5.0
# 3 2013-01-16              1            2.5
# 4 2013-01-19             14           15.0
```

Comment: You used `y[2:3]` but is there a placeholder if the number of columns is unknown?

Comment: If you know the columns you **don't** want to apply this to, then you can use negative indices, `y[-1]` in the current case.

Answer (score 1):

As Stephen mentions, you need to convert to numeric

```
data.frame(y[1], lapply(y[-1], function(x) as.numeric(gsub("<", "", x)) / 2))

#         Date concentration1 concentration2
# 1 2013-01-01              6            5.0
# 2 2013-01-10              5            5.0
# 3 2013-01-16              1            2.5
# 4 2013-01-19              7            7.5
```

---

In response to comments.

First make sure strings are read as character when creating the data.frame. Then avoid loops (or *apply) by converting to matrix and let R do it's vectorized magic. This won't overwrite the original data.frame, but rather create a new one.

```
y <- data.frame(Date, concentration1, concentration2, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
y$Date <- as.Date(y$Date)

val <- as.matrix(y[,-1])
ind <- startsWith(val, "<")
val[ind] <- as.numeric(sub("<", "", val[ind])) / 2
data.frame(y[1], val)

#         Date concentration1 concentration2
# 1 2013-01-01             12             10
# 2 2013-01-10              5              5
# 3 2013-01-16              1            2.5
# 4 2013-01-19             14             15
```

Comment: I believe this is not the expected output, not all should be divided by 2 as I understand it

Comment: Right, only the entries with a < should then subsequently divided by 2

Answer (score 1):

1) You need to remember the index of the fields with '<'

2) Remove the '<' as suggested

3) divide by 2

4) again convert the date to date format

```
idx=lapply(y, function(x) grep("<",x) )
y=lapply(y, function(x) gsub("<", "", x)) 
y=data.frame(mapply(function(x,i){if(length(i)>0) x[i]=as.numeric(x[i])/2; x},y ,idx ))
y$Date <- as.Date(y$Date)
```

Result:

```
        Date concentration1 concentration2
1 2013-01-01             12             10
2 2013-01-10              5              5
3 2013-01-16              1            2.5
4 2013-01-19             14             15
```

Comment: How can I convert the concentrations from factor to numeric within the code `y=data.frame(mapply(function(x,i){if(length(i)>0) x[i]=as.numeric(x[i])/2; x},y ,idx ))`?

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot, I used `y <- data.frame(Date, concentration1,concentration2, stringsAsFactors=F)` to avoid it.

Comment: You could do `y=data.frame(mapply(function(x,i){x=as.character(x); if(length(i)>0) x[i]=as.numeric(x[i])/2; x},y ,idx ))`

Comment: `y <- data.frame(Date, concentration1,concentration2, stringsAsFactors=F)` converts all to characters and `y=data.frame(mapply(function(x,i){x=as.character(x); if(length(i)>0) x[i]=as.numeric(x[i])/2; x},y ,idx ))` returns all columsn as factors. What I would like to do is just have the two concentrations columns as numeric.